# Problem of modulus of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

If $a$ is a complex number $a\neq 0$. Under that conditions $|a|\leq |a+z|$ with $z$ complex number?

Comment: @Andres http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That condition is equivalent to $d(a,0) \le d(a,-z)$.   Time to draw a picture and see what is happening.